# Finding optimal elements from an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I need to devise an algorithm that finds me the most optimal elements from a list in python. I have a cd that holds 700mb. And an array of 300 randomly generated file sizes varying from 30 - 90 mb. It needs to fill the cd the most optimal way, that minimum room is wasted ( looking through all possible ways) I guess it's similar to the knapsack problem, only that it has only 1 array and a limit.
Since I'm totally new to the algorithm and datastructure scene, I have no idea how to implement this using python

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's exactly the knapsack problem, with one dimension.

Comment: I've made the assumption that you want to use all the files?  I guess that is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

As @payne points out in his comment, this is really the same as the knapsack problem. The solution is therefore a simple dynamic programming algorithm.

Say the files are arranged one after another in some order in a list. At first, you have the choice of either choosing to include the first file or skipping it. If you choose to include it, the space you have available will decrease by the size of that file. If you choose to skip it, the space available remains unchanged. Now, you can arrive to the second file in two states. In one, you have chosen the first file and thus have less space, while in the other you have skipped the first file and have more space. For each of these scenarios, you can again choose to include or skip over the second file.

Notice you can define your state simply by the file which you are considering at the moment and the available space that you have. Once you have moved past the last file or the space has run out, you have come to the end of that line of choices.

This yields a simple recurrence:

```
min_waste(index,space)={
   o if space=0     # no more space available, so 0 wastage

   space if index>=size(files) # no more files left, whatever is left is wasted

   min_waste(index+1,space)  if size(files[index])>space  # current file is too large skip ahead

   min( min_waste(index+1,space), min_waste(index+1,space-size(files[index])) ) otherwise
   # minimum of choosing this one and skipping ahead 
}
```

You can choose to implement this by filling up a table (i.e. 2D array) bottom up, or just write this up as a recursive function and memoize.

This gives you the minimum wastage, but not which files were selected to achieve it. But you can easily modify it to save information about the choice it makes in each state and use that to build up the series of choices from the starting state.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably not efficient to find the absolute most optimal way.  But you can use some rules of thumb, like take the largest files first, and then fill the remaining space with the first file that fits until the space is too small for any more to fit.  See [Bin Packing Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing).  The optimal simple algorithm is First Fit Decreasing.  Sort all the files by size from largest to smallest.  Then place each file on the first cd where there is enough room for it to fit, until all the files are used up.

**Edit**

It is likely that all of the files put together do not exactly equal some number of cd's.  For instance, if the total of the files is 1.6GB, that's two cd's with a little left over, even if they packed perfectly.  So if you already know that 3 cd's are the minimum required, and you try a few combinations until you get it fitting on 3 cd's, why does it need to be optimized any more than that?  You can't save any more cd's than the theoretical minimum.

Comment: I thought about that, but I was told that it has to be the most optimal way. It can be looked as a ship, that has to fit maximum amount of cargo without exceeding the limit. The more cargo, the less it has to sail back and forwards for transport thus minimizing cost of operation.

Comment: @jorgen: Correct.  However, this is an NP-Hard problem, and for 300 randomly generated files, you will be trying out `300!` scenarios which is roughly `10^1000`.  All the computers in the world couldn't test all possibilities over the time length of the age of the universe!

Comment: Oh.. you're right. Infact there was a slight typo I have to admit. The number was 30 not 300..
Sorry about that

Comment: To add to my previous comment, there are a few strategies that will give you probably `95%` or more of the optimal solution, in a relatively short amount of time.  Squeezing out the last bit of optimal solutions will take **years** of time for a few percentage points.  It's not really worth it.

Comment: @jorgen: Even for 30 files, that is `30!` which is `265252859812191058636308480000000` possible combinations to try and still impractical.  Using a heuristic approach will be more than sufficient and there is little to gain to try every possible combination.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I can see the problem. But can you suggest me some of those strategies, that will give me the closest answer in a short time?

Comment: @jorgen: First fit decreasing is the best simple algorithm.  I updated my post with a description of how it works.

Comment: @mellamokb There are definitely not `30!` combinations to try for a brute force since the order doesn't matter, pretty sure it comes out to `1073741824` which is much more manageable.

Comment: @Andrew: Now that I think about it, the number of combinations would depend on the number of 'bins' or cd's.  There will probably be 3 cd's, and each file goes into one of the 3 cd's.  There are 6 combinations that are identical, so the total number is roughly `3^30 / 6 = 34315188682441.5`.  How did you come up with your number?

Comment: @mellamokb 30 tracks, each track is either included in the cd or not, `2^30 = 1073741824`.  You probably wouldn't need to try all of those because as soon as you pass the space limit none of the rest of the tracks can be included.  The method you used for 3 cds seems reasonable, I'm puzzled by the half of a combination though :)

Comment: @Andrew: I know what my problem is.  I've been assuming that he wants to use all the files.  I see now he wants to use as many files as will fit on a single cd.

Comment: @mellamokb what you are describing is the number of permutations (order matters) as opposed to the number of combinations (like in this case, where order does not matter)... which should be considerably less, around 2,035,800 possibilities.  700/30 (the min file size) = 23 files per CD  Combination(30,23) = 30!/(23!(30-23)!) = 2,035,800    incidentally, C(30,7) --the number of 90 mb files that fit a 700 mb CD-- is also 2,035,800